# Iterating over elements in pandas dataframe-Error

Tags: pandas

I am trying to select rows by looking up keywords through columns. What I have (not very important info) is a `database.txt` file like this:

```
Source  Reference_id    Method  Evaluation  EC value    Enzyme  RxnString   Reaction        Kprime  Temp        pH  
ho  07LIN/ALG   s   A   1.1.1.87    homoisocitrate dehydrogenase    C05662 + C00003 = C00322 + C00288 + C00004  "(1R,2S)-1-hydroxybutane-1,2,4-tricarboxylate(aq) + NAD(ox) = 2-oxoadipate(aq) + carbon dioxide(aq) + NAD(red)"     0.45    298.15      7.5 
as  63GRE   s   C   3.5.4.9 methenyltetrahydrofolate cyclohydrolase C00445 + C00001 = C00234    "5,10-methenyltetrahydrofolate(aq) + H2O(l) = 10-formyltetrahydrofolate(aq)"        4.2 298.15      6.5 
H/DEN_1165  67ENG/DEN   s   B   4.2.1.3 aconitate hydratase C00311 = C00158 isocit(aq) = cit(aq)        18  310.15      7.3 2.96
G/DEN_1165  67ENG/DEN   s   B   4.2.1.3 aconitate hydratase C00311 = C00158 isocit(aq) = cit(aq)        25  310.15      7.3 2.8
p C00002 + C00085 = C00008 + C00354 "ATP(aq) + D-p6p(aq) = ADP(aq) + D-fructose 1,6-bisphosphate(aq)"       2900    303.15      8   
H/OEH_1552  99HUT/OEH   calorimetry B   3.2.1.26    #NAME?  C00089 + C00001 = C00031 + C00095   sucrose(aq) + H2O(l) = D-glucose(aq) + D-fructose(aq)           298.15      4.6
```

The code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.read_csv('database.txt', sep="\t")
data
```

This works.

Then I need those rows in column "Reactions" where keywords ATP, ADP or AMP appear, so:

```
data.loc[data['Reaction'].isin(['ATP(aq)','ADP(aq)', 'AMP(aq)'])]
```

but get

---

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _has_valid_type(self, key, axis)
   1410                 if key not in ax:
-> 1411                     error()
   1412             except TypeError as e:
```

Any help with this problem?

Comment: What is `print (data.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: I can't see where is that..@jezrael

Comment: It is new code, it is for convert columns to list for check if value `Reaction` or some traling whitespace like `' Reaction'`

Comment: `'Reaction'` @jezrael

Comment: OK, so `print(data['Reaction'])` working perfectly?

Comment: yes, that's right @jezrael

Comment: and `print (data['Reaction'].isin(['ATP(aq)','ADP(aq)']))` failed?

Comment: No, it seems right @jezrael

Comment: And `print(data.loc[data['Reaction'].isin(['ATP(aq)','ADP(aq)', 'AMP(aq)'])])` return error? I guess not, or?

Comment: @jezrael to the previous comment, it returns false where there should be some trues

Comment: It returns "empty dataframe" @jezrael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) for check substrings:

```
import re

L = ['ATP(aq)','ADP(aq)','AMP(aq)']
pat = '|'.join(['{}'.format(re.escape(c)) for c in L])

df = data.loc[data['Reaction'].str.contains(pat)]
```

EDIT:

If need remove duplicates by column `Reaction` add [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Reaction': {0: 'ATP(aq) + D-p6p(aq) = ADP(aq) + D-fructose 1,6-bisphosphate(aq)', 
                                  1: '5,10-methenyltetrahydrofolate(aq) + H2O(l) = 10-formyltetrahydrofolate(aq)',
                                  2: 'isocitrate(aq) = citrate(aq)', 
                                  3: 'ATP(aq) + D-p6p(aq) = ADP(aq) + D-fructose 1,6-bisphosphate(aq)'}})
print (data)
                                            Reaction
0  ATP(aq) + D-p6p(aq) = ADP(aq) + D-fructose 1,6...
1  5,10-methenyltetrahydrofolate(aq) + H2O(l) = 1...
2                       isocitrate(aq) = citrate(aq)
3  ATP(aq) + D-p6p(aq) = ADP(aq) + D-fructose 1,6...
```

---

```
import re

L = ['ATP(aq)','ADP(aq)','AMP(aq)']
pat = '|'.join(['{}'.format(re.escape(c)) for c in L])
df1 = data.loc[data['Reaction'].str.contains(pat)]
print (df1)
                                            Reaction
0  ATP(aq) + D-p6p(aq) = ADP(aq) + D-fructose 1,6...
3  ATP(aq) + D-p6p(aq) = ADP(aq) + D-fructose 1,6...

df2 = data.loc[data['Reaction'].str.contains(pat)].drop_duplicates('Reaction')
print (df2)
                                            Reaction
0  ATP(aq) + D-p6p(aq) = ADP(aq) + D-fructose 1,6...
```

Comment: `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:6: UserWarning: This pattern has match groups. To actually get the groups, use str.extract.`

Comment: OK, what is `print (data.head().to_dict())` ? Because I cannot copy your data with tab separator.

Comment: hmm I see. I didn't know that. It is: `'Reaction': {0: '(1R,2S)-1-hydroxybutane-1,2,4-tricarboxylate(aq) + NAD(ox) = 2-oxoadipate(aq) + carbon dioxide(aq) + NAD(red)', 1: '5,10-methenyltetrahydrofolate(aq) + H2O(l) = 10-formyltetrahydrofolate(aq)', 2: 'isocitrate(aq) = citrate(aq)', 3: 'isocitrate(aq) = citrate(aq)', 4: 'isocitrate(aq) = citrate(aq)'}`

Comment: Is it possible to avoid repeating when in a row there is more than one of the keywords?

Comment: Not sure if understand, `contains` check if all values in list `L` are in `Reaction` column. Or do you need extract this values? Or count how many values from `L` are in each row?

Comment: I need a dataFrame with only those rows which cointains ATP,ADP or AMP. But on the new dataFrame (as in the original) there must be no repeated rows, am I clear?

Comment: I think you need remove duplicates by column `Reaction` use `df = data.loc[data['Reaction'].str.contains(pat)].drop_duplicates('Reaction')`

Comment: It doesn't remove some repited rows. I will try a bit and ask if can't solve the problem..thanks a lot..

Comment: Hmmm, then it seems there is some difference like whitespace, then pandas cannot remove it.